# Check if an intermediate string starts-ends with certain pattern and update the string

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have a string like :
**`String str = "startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:;renewDate;"`** 
Required multiple operation on the string.I need to get a String and extract different sub-strings using a delimiter **(";")** then again extract different sub-strings to form a key-value using a delimiter **(":")**. If against the key their is no value present the update with diff-diff default value like (**"01/01/2000","01/01/1900"** since both are of type Date).
if you notice for **renewDate** field their is no separator **(":")** in this case we need to append the separator along with default value **(:01/01/1900)** so that my expected result would be like : 
**`String str = "startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:01/01/2000;renewDate:01/01/1900;"`**

I have tried below regex but it is not working for all scenario :

`String regExpression = "(?<=\\bendDate:)[;]+"
 str = str.replaceAll(regExpression , "01/01/2000");`

Can any one guide me how to achive the result using regex.Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said we can use regex pattern to replace the value. Adding to his answer, the only change I recommend to add colon(:) as optional in pattern used for both renewDate  and endDate in text.

```
    String endDate = "01/01/2000";
    String renewDate = "01/01/1900";
    String str = "startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:;renewDate;";
    str = str.replaceAll(";endDate:?;", ";endDate:"+endDate+";");
    str = str.replaceAll(";renewDate:?;", ";renewDate:"+renewDate+";");
    System.out.println(str);
```

This will give the output as below

```
startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:01/01/2000;renewDate:01/01/1900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex replacement, we can try:

```
String endDate = "01/01/2000";
String renewDate = "01/01/1900";
String str = "startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:;renewDate:;";
String output = str.replaceAll("\\bendDate:;", "endDate:" + endDate + ";")
                   .replaceAll("\\brenewDate:;", "renewDate:" + renewDate + ";");

System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:01/01/2000;renewDate:01/01/1900;
```

The logic here is to only target empty end and renew date fields, including default values if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, separate strings based on your first delimiter `;` and then `:`.

```
String str = "startDate:23/04/2016;endDate:;renewDate;";
String dates[] = str.split(";");
for(String date : dates){
    String default[] = date.split(":");
    output.append(default[0] + ":" + (default.length > 1 ? default[1] : defaultDate));
}
```